# How to get Wireless working on Acer Aspire 5742?

Tags: 11.10, acer, wireless

I've upgraded to Oneiric and cannot get wifi to work at all. Previous versions from Maverick onward have ahd the smae initial problems, but were overcome with the activation of hardware keys. 
This time however  it didn't work. Wireless activation can be toggled on and off, the Broadcom drivers are listed as installed and active. In the indicator menu Wireless is greyed out and stated as "disconnected".
"rfkill list" 
Gives:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I'm pretty sure that acer-wmi is meant to be present, but I'm no expert. Someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is checking the "Additional Drives" and look to see if you can enable your networking from a driver that needs to be enabled.

- [How do I install additional drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-a-graphics-or-wireless-card-driver/47511#47511)